# Late Bind to Queue in Azure Function using IBinder

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

The [Azure Function dotnet class library docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#binding-at-runtime) detail how to use an IBinder to connect to any storage endpoint.

How to late bind to a Queue?

The example given shows binding to a Blob container as a TextWriter.

```
[FunctionName("CreateBlobUsingBinder")]
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items-source-4")] string myQueueItem,
    IBinder binder,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"CreateBlobUsingBinder function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    using (var writer = binder.Bind<TextWriter>(new BlobAttribute(
                $"samples-output/{myQueueItem}", FileAccess.Write)))
    {
        writer.Write("Hello World!");
    };
}
```

In the 'Attribute' syntax it would be:

```
[QueueTrigger("inputQ")] InputDTO inputobject,
[Queue("output{clientid}Q")] OutputDTO outputobject,
IBinder binder{
...
}
```

but in my situation 'clientid' is not known until after binding occours.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use an `ICollector<T>`.

```
var clientid = inputclientid;
var practiceMessageQueue = await binder.BindAsync<ICollector<OutputDTO>>(
    new QueueAttribute($"output{clientid}Q")).ConfigureAwait(false);
```